# category id in prestashop tag link

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I am currently using this code in prestashop to display the tags in the product details page

```
{foreach from=Tag::getProductTags(Tools::getValue('id_product')) key=k item=v}
    {foreach from=$v item=value}
        <li><a href="{$link->getPageLink('search', true, NULL, "tag={$value|urlencode}")}" title="{l s='Find more'} {$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{$value|escape:html:'UTF-8'}</a></li>
    {/foreach}
```

When a user clicks on the link it opens the search page with the tags. 
I need to use the same thing but limit the search in the current category id the product is in.

Can anyone help?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look here:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/4376

As I see that you're familiar with a coding you should easily implement above solution to your shop :)

Comment: My coding skills are not that good :-) I would realy be happy if you could help more.